# how to extract all images from a .ppt file using Android?

Tags: android, image, apache-poi, extract

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to extract all images from a .ppt file using Android with help of Apache poi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9716033/how-to-extract-all-images-from-a-ppt-file-using-android-with-help-of-apache-poi)

I am working on ppt viewer for Android . I have extracted all the text from a ppt with the help of Apache POI API but unable to extract images  in a ppt file. I would be happy to know the results.... My codes are here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9716033/how-to-extract-all-images-from-a-ppt-file-using-android-with-help-of-apache-poi)

Answer (score 2):

Check the following code for reading all the images in an PPTX file :

```
SlideShow ppt = new SlideShow(new HSLFSlideShow("slideshow.ppt"));

  //extract all pictures contained in the presentation
  PictureData[] pdata = ppt.getPictureData();
  for (int i = 0; i < pdata.length; i++){
    PictureData pict = pdata[i];

    // picture data
    byte[] data = pict.getData();

    int type = pict.getType();
    String ext;
    switch (type){
      case Picture.JPEG: ext=".jpg"; break;
      case Picture.PNG: ext=".png"; break;
      case Picture.WMF: ext=".wmf"; break;
      case Picture.EMF: ext=".emf"; break;
      case Picture.PICT: ext=".pict"; break;
      default: continue;
    }
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("pict_"+i + ext);
      out.write(data);
      out.close();

  }
```

References : http://poi.apache.org/slideshow/how-to-shapes.html